# Postfix Notation, Find the Bug//

Tags: c++, postfix-mta

Preferred language using C++//

Basically the expression below has been converted into a C++ postfix expression. Now i need to reckon the result.

I used deque somehow, instead of stack, because i tried using stack and it didn't seem to work. but there's bug.

7
8 9 + 1 7 - *

-102

Here's my code:

```
string line; inf >> line;

deque <int> stack;

for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i+=2){

    if(line.at(i) == '*'){
        stack.push_back(stack.pop_back() * stack.pop_back());
    }

    else if(line.at(i) == '+'){
        stack.push_back(stack.pop_back() + stack.pop_back());
    }

    else if(line.at(i) == '-'){
        stack.push_back(-stack.pop_back() + stack.pop_back());
    }

    else stack.push_back(line.at(i)- '0');

}

outf << stack.pop_back() << endl;

return 0;
```

}
With the code above can i alter with a small tweak and have it change into a Prefix Notation.

I still prefer using the std::deque STL Library from C++.

Comment: *i tried using stack and it didn't seem to work.* --  Strange, since this problem is solved by using a stack.  Why didn't you simply fix the bugs in your code?   There is absolutely nothing wrong with the stack class.

Comment: `#include <stack>...stack<int> s;...s.pop()...s.push()...` etc.  Explain why this would be any different than what you are trying to do with `std::deque`?  If deque doesn't "work", what's the next container class you will try?

Comment: Is the bug you are referring to the invalid postfix expression? Something is missing, or is it deliberately not valid?

Comment: That expression `7 8 9 + 1 7 - *` is certainly an invalid infix expression.  Maybe your "bug" is that you failed to check for validity, and just assumed that the expression is valid.

Comment: The code above gives me compile error, in codeblocks. The input expression is one line string with an always valid postfix notation. I tried to keep it simple by using the deque stl.

Comment: @PhilAnder The `std::stack` class uses `stack.top()` to get the item on top of the stack, and `pop()` to remove the item.  You were probably using the `stack` class incorrectly.

Comment: I don't which implementation you are using, but `std::deque::pop_back` does not return anything, so `stack.pop_back() * stack.pop_back()` should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You're using std::deque<>::pop_back() wrong.
It just removes the last element from the deque and doesn't return anything, so all the `stack.pop_back() + stack.pop_back()` etc. won't compile at all.
Instead, for each `stack.pop_back()` you will have to do a `operand = stack.back(); mydeque.pop_back();` instead. You could wrap this in a small function:

```
int pop_stack( std::deque<int>& _stack )
{
    int result = _stack.back();
    _stack.pop_back();
    return result;
}
```

and then replace all your `stack.pop_back()` by this function: `pop_stack(stack)`

As a `std::stack` behaves pretty much the same (except the method naming), there's no reason at all to use a `std::deque`, you could use a stack as well.

[std::deque::pop_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_back/)

[std::stack::pop()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/)

Besides, it seems there is just one operand too many:
`7 8 9 + 1 7 - *` evaluates correctly to `-102` - and a lost `7` down in the stack.

Evaluation by operands:

`7 8 9 +`

`7 17`

`7 17 1 7 -`

`7 17 -6`

`7 17 -6 *`

Final:

`7 -102`